# Evaluate the inverse trigonometric integral

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral:$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{\tan^{-1} x}{\tan^{-1} \frac {1}{x^2-3x+3}} dx$

On applying the property $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$ I dont seem to reach any where

Comment: Are you sure that it is $x^2-3x+3$ and not $x^2-3x+2$? If it is $x^2-3x+2$, then the property you have mentioned works.

Comment: It works but as i said i could not reach any conclusion

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$\dfrac1{x^2-3x+3}=\dfrac{x-1-(x-2)}{1+(x-2)(x-1)}$$

Then apply the formula you've mentioned

and use $\arctan(-y)=-\arctan y$

Comment: Nice insight but the sign is reversed.

Comment: @RonGordon, Thanks for your observation.

Comment: After this ,what to do

Comment: @PankajSinha, What is $\tan(A-B)$ formula?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  I  &=\int_{1}^{2} \frac{\tan^{-1} x}{\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{x^{2}-3x+3}}dx \\
     &=\int_{1}^{2} \frac{\tan^{-1} (3-x)}
                         {\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{(3-x)^{2}-3(3-x)+3}}dx \\
     &=\int_{1}^{2} \frac{\tan^{-1} (3-x)}{\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{x^{2}-3x+3}}dx \\
  2I &=\int_{1}^{2} \frac{\tan^{-1} x+\tan^{-1} (3-x)}
                         {\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{x^{2}-3x+3}}dx \\
     &=\int_{1}^{2} \frac{\tan^{-1} x+\tan^{-1} (3-x)}
                         {\cot^{-1} (x^{2}-3x+3)} dx \\
     &=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1} (\frac{3+u}{2})+\tan^{-1} (\frac{3-u}{2})}
                         {2\cot^{-1} (\frac{u^{2}+3}{4})} du \\
   I &=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1} (\frac{3+u}{2})+\tan^{-1} (\frac{3-u}{2})}
                         {\cot^{-1} (\frac{u^{2}+3}{4})} du
\end{align*}